# How to do Clean URL properly with params?

Tags: php, .htaccess

OK I am using this right now and its partly working

when i write `www.example.com/foo` it goes to `www.example.com/foo.php` 
but when i try and pass something like `www.example.com/foo/1` it gives

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /Test/foo/1.php was not found on this server.

it takes the `1` makes it as `1.php` which is wrong

I want to keep it as dynamic as possible so i want to redirect as `$1.php` but be able to pass at least one param

I do not want to hard code each file and param for in the .htaccess, is this possible and how would i do it?

here is what i have right now

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy this is what i got from that question this works `www.example.com/foo` but then when i write `www.example.com/foo/1` its give a `The requested URL /Test/foo/1` was not found on this server for some reason? when there is a file named foo : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]`